# Python3 error while importing flask app context

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have a folder structure like so:

```
flaskapp/
----app/
    ----__init__.py
    ----blueprints/
----tests/
    ----conftest.py
----run.py
```

where **init**.py contains the code to create the flask app context:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

and run.py contains:

```
from app import app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I run the app with `flask run`, it works fine

When I try to import app into conftest.py, it throws a ModuleNotFound error `No module named 'app'`. Code as follows:

```
from app import app
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conftest.py file is inside the tests directory and is trying to refer to a module from its parent directory, which is not possible as is.

Here is what you can use to achieve what you want

```
import os
import sys
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.append(parentdir)
```

Put the above provided snippet in conftest.py before

> from app import app